# How to get Canonical Names using ARSoft.Tools.Net library?

Tags: c#

So I'm creating a windows forms app that takes a domain name and returns info about it such as its dmarc records and cname record. Everything else seems to work fine but I can't get the cname for the domain name

```
        public string DomainNameInput = null;
        public Form2(string s)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DomainNameInput = s;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line = null;
            var resolver = new DnsStubResolver();

            line += "DMARC RECORD\n============\n";
            var dmarc = resolver.Resolve<ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns.TxtRecord>("_dmarc." + DomainNameInput, RecordType.Txt);
            foreach (var record in dmarc)
            {
                line += record.TextData + "\n";
            }

            line += "\n\nCNAME RECORD\n===========\n";
            var domainCName = resolver.Resolve<CNameRecord>("autodiscover." + DomainNameInput, RecordType.CName);
            foreach (var record in domainCName)
            {
                line += record.CanonicalName + "\n";
            }

            label1.Text = line;
        }
```

Inputting "google.com" as `DomainNameInput` outputs:

```
DMARC RECORD
============
v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:mailauth-reports@google.com

CNAME RECORD
============
```

As you can see there is no output underneath the "CNAME RECORD". How do I actually retrieve and output the cname for any given domain name

Project uses [ARSoft.Tools.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ARSoft.Tools.Net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day,

You are missing a ToString() method call after the CanonicalName object (TextData is an actual string):

```
foreach (var record in domainCName)
{
    line += record.CanonicalName.ToString() + "\n";
}
```